# Creating regex for a specific character separated string

Tags: regex

I'm creating a regex for the following character separated string:

```
12345678;12345678;12345678;...
```

So as you can see each value must have 8 digits and '00000000' is not allowed (everything else is allowed). Can someone help me finding the correct regex because i'm not so familiar with this.

the regex for a single value is (every check that is in this regex must also be applied on the regex for the character separated string):

```
^(?!00000000)\d{8}$
```

I only need to make this 'multi valued'

And can I also adjust the regex so a ';' at the end is acceptable? something like: ';?'

Comment: What do you want to use your regexp for?  Also is there a specific reason that you want to disallow the all 0 number?

Comment: What does "must also accept a single value" mean? Do you mean a single 8 digit number, or do you mean a single digit?

Comment: OK.  The `(?!00000000)` will disallow all 0 input in the single value case you provided a regexp for

Comment: @Ken White I mean it must accept single 8 digit number

Comment: Also, you haven't answered my most imporant question.  What do you want to use this regexp for?  Do you want to check that the string matches the format you specify or do you want to extract information from a string you already know matches this format?

Comment: @Taemyr It is only needed for matching, to check if a string matches the regex

Comment: @Ozkan If it is only for matching, I suppose ^\d{8}(;\d{8})*$ would do.

Comment: `;?` is an optional ;.  So adding that will allow your string to end in a ;.  You can't add it at the end of the regexp because `$;?` means, the end of the string followed by an optional ;.  You have to add it imidiately before the `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "00000000" is valid input the regexp for the single value case should be just;

```
^\d{8}$
```

Ie. match a complete string containing excactly 8 digits.

Extending this to more groups would be

```
^\d{8}(;\d{8})*$
```

Ie. match a complete string containing exactly 8 digits, followed by 0 or more groups of a comma and another 8 digits.

Since "00000000" is not valid you just apply the `(?!00000000)` negative lookahead to exclude it.

```
^(?!00000000)\d{8}(;(?!00000000)\d{8})*$
```

To allow the string to optionally end with a semicolon add `;?` before the end of string anchor `$`.  Ie:

```
^(?!00000000)\d{8}(;(?!00000000)\d{8})*;?$
```

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong, 00000000 isn't allowed, how should the regex be adjusted then?

Comment: @Taemyr: the separator is a ``;``, not a comma. I had the same idea as you otherwise.

Comment: @Chop Thanks.  I did check the input string, but apparently I still managed to misread.

Comment: @Ozkan The negative lookahead in your original post still works.  Answer edited.

Comment: @Ozkan: You need to edit your question and update the requirements. Be more clear when you do - you've said `00000000` is not allowed; what about `00000001`? What about `10000000`? Stop, think about your **specific requirements**, and then edit your question to include them, clearly stated.